# Earth leaves IQ suppression zone

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to find a book I remember reading, one I'd like to re-read.  I saw it  probably decades ago.   Basic premise is that earth has been stuck in a zone that somehow suppresses intelligence.   When it leaves, everyday people go genius.      I remember a throw away line early in the book with a scene about a kid who was toying with high mathematics and saying later that day he had reinvented calculus.    I remember it causing chaos on Earth -- and I remember them doing some sort of space journey later in the book to test the theory that there was a zone of IQ suppression.   I think I remember reading it as a small paperback. There might have been something about some animals becoming sentient as well, unless I'm confusing still another story.  I don't remember the title or author.   I'm thinking it had a cover possibly with a chimp riding an elephant into a farm or low-urban area or something  -- unless my memory is mixing books.

This was long before Vernor Vinge's books.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Classic book. [Brain Wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_Wave) by Poul Anderson. The cover shown on the [Goodreads page](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1228628.Brain_Wave) is exactly as you described.

Comment: Poul Anderson did book signings at a book store owned by someone my dad knew. I think my copy of this book might be autographed.