# Sudden increase in intelligence

Tags: story-identification

Title and/or author of a book or story?

Backstory is that our solar system has been in an energy field that suppresses thought.  Humans and all other animals evolved the level of intelligence they needed in spite of it.  The actual story starts when our solar system exited the field.  Suddenly everything is chaos because animals are as smart as we had been, and the differences between spouses are magnified till they are unable to relate to each other.

Comment: And [Due to natural rotation of Milky Way all Earth life gets increased intelligence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90595/due-to-natural-rotation-of-milky-way-all-earth-life-gets-increased-intelligence), and [Earth leaves IQ suppression zone](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37047/earth-leaves-iq-suppression-zone).

Comment: If the story is *Brain Wave* let us know and we can mark this as a duplicate. Thanks :-)

Comment: All three of them point to Brain Wave, and from the wikipedia description, I am sure that is it.  Thanks!  (Your first link is the best of the three)

Comment: Thanks :-) A lot of the classic books have been asked about many times!